# dx-data-grid removes row from grid even though delete fails on database

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I'm new to javascript and web and I'm having a few troubles with the devexpress grid. My problem is as soon as the code steps into the api, even before I'm doing db.SaveChanges(); it removes my row from the grid. The delete is then correctly blocked by a db constraint so it fails. But the row does not return to the grid and only refreshes when the datasource is updated which does not feel like it's the proper way to do it. Any best practices for handling this?

So on my datagridoptions in my controller i have my event:

```
onRowRemoving: function (info) {vm.DeleteFunction(info.data);}
```

and inside my delete function I call my api with something like this at the end of it:

```
.then(function (response) {
                    //successfull
                }, function (response) {
                    //not successfull
                })
```

I'm guessing I should add something around here.